# Ecommerce: how can i do the tracking procedure?

Tags: laravel, e-commerce, tracking

In the backend, I have fields for the seller to include tracking number and tracking courier. What are the other things that I need to include. What are the other informations. I'm trying to enter the tracking number and the courier to the order_shipping db table. I'm using laravel so which api should I use?

Comment: What api / courier service are u using, more information is needed to answers this correctly!

Comment: that is one of question. What should i use. Which api. courier service is ups, fedex right?